# Get a "root controller" from a SwiftUI app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm working on a SwiftUI App and one of the frameworks that I have to integrate needs a UIViewController to display a view inside.

I guess there is no way to get a rootController from the App struct.
I tried to create a UIViewControllerRepresentable that hosted my View, exposed a UIViewController property so that I can use it, but it did not work.

Let's say I have this view

```swift
struct VideoView: View {
   let videoManager: VideoManager // basically one method to show a video in a view controller
   var body: some View {
      Button("show Video") {
         videoManager.showVideo(in: /* UIVIewController */)
      }
   }
}
```

How can I feed an actual presented ViewController here ? (and no, I have no other options than using this lib, so I needed one way or another a viewController :-) )

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please show your attempt to use UIViewControllerRepresentable, that is probably the way to do this. What "didn't work" about it?

Comment: Just put the button and your lib code in a UIViewController. Then put that new controller in a UIViewRepresentable

Comment: @jrturton : basically straight forward, like the example from shubham mahadik (execept that I added my ContentView as a UIHostingView inside the makeUIViewController (`controller.addChild(_:)`). But 2 issues here : I cannot access the viewController from the ContentView (though is is inside a controller) and for some reasons, my ContentView never showed :-/